# Getting information from different Laravel relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to get information from 3 tables in Laravel 5.8 but so far i have just come up with nothing.

The 3 tables look something similar to the following;

```
polls
    id - integer
    name - string
    status - tinyint

poll_options
    id - integer
    poll_id - integer
    image_id - integer
    status - tinyint

poll_images
    id - integer
    filename - varchar
```

A poll has several poll options, those poll options have 1 images each.

I would like to get poll options with the poll status of 1 and any images that have poll options with a status of 1

I need the get the filename, the poll option id and the poll id.

I'm so confused

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use query builder, then it may be:

```
$results = DB::table('polls')->select('polls.id','poll_options.id','poll_images.filename')                            
                             ->join('poll_options','polls.id','=','poll_options.poll_id')
                             ->join('poll_images','poll_options.image_id','=','poll_images.id')
                             ->where([['polls.status','=','1'],
                                      ['poll_options.status','=','1'],])
                             ->get();
```

Comment: Hey, thats pretty much what I was looking for! The only thing is that it doesnt include the polls.id in the output

Comment: Ahhh i just had to change polls.id to polls.id as poll_id ... Perfect ... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use Many to Many(pivot) relationships. By this, you can create two model classes and then use the relationship `belongsToMany`. Below is the reference:-

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Im wondering, only one poll option can belong to a poll, would that still class this as a many to many (pivot) relationship?

Comment: Doesnt a many to many only use 2 tables and creates the pivot? ... In my example im using 3 tables